# In-memory database means mmap with mlock

Tags: c, database, memory-management

there are In-memory databases like MariaDB (MEMORY engine) and ... but I can't understand it ! In-memory means data locked into memory (not virtual memory) but in operating systems, we only have virtual memory functions (mmap, ...) ! But then I thought maybe they use `mlock()` function to lock the virtual memory into memory ... I'm right ? Or ...

Comment: The term "virtual memory" doesn't mean swap-space (if that's what you think?), it means the whole memory-map the process is using from the operating system.